# werkzeug's LocalProxy.__local, where is it initialized?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I am curious about how `LocalProxy` from the [`werkzeug`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/src/werkzeug/local.py) package works. Specifically, where is the `__local` field initialized?

```
@implements_bool
class LocalProxy(object):
    __slots__ = ("__local", "__dict__", "__name__", "__wrapped__")

    def __init__(self, local, name=None):
        object.__setattr__(self, "_LocalProxy__local", local)
        object.__setattr__(self, "__name__", name)
        if callable(local) and not hasattr(local, "__release_local__"):
            object.__setattr__(self, "__wrapped__", local)

    def _get_current_object(self):
        if not hasattr(self.__local, "__release_local__"):
            return self.__local()
        try:
            return getattr(self.__local, self.__name__)
        except AttributeError:
            raise RuntimeError("no object bound to %s" % self.__name__)

    ...
```

There are no other places in `LocalProxy` class definition that reference `self.__local`, and it seems to me that `self.__local` is not initialized anywhere. Is it somehow magically aliased to `self._LocalProxy__local`?

Comment: It is set right in the first line of ``__init__``, namely ``object.__setattr__(self, "_LocalProxy__local", local)``.

Answer (score 1):

What you call `aliasing` is called `name mangling` in Python.

Given this example:

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name
```

`name` is then available as `Customer._customer__name`.

While this is really rarely used, the intention is to make the access a bit **harder**. For whatever reason you want this.

The other interesting part of your code example is called `slots`.

This is a way to define/initialize attributes in an advanced way. It helps reducing memory and it prevents new attributes to be dynamically defined.